# Why is this patch failing

Tags: patch

It's a very simple patch...

- I've tried dos2unix on both files.
- I've tried the --ignore-whitespace option.
- 'file' command returns that both ASCII text.
- I removed all whitespace at the end of the patch file, but I also tried with 1 and 2 empty lines at the end.

I'm applying the patch via composer and this is important because I need to be able to deploy the patch through CI/CD.

I am using cweagans/composer-patches@1.7.3 package. I tried upgrading to 2.x-beta and encountered the same issues.

To rule out syntax issues, I tried applying the patch via PHPStorm Git utility and this worked without issue.

If use --verbose with the composer command, I can see the command it is using to apply the patch.  When I try to apply the patch directly with this command I get the same error, shown here:

```
patch '-p1' --verbose --ignore-whitespace --no-backup-if-mismatch -d 'web/modules/contrib/activitytracking' < /var/www/html/patches/activitytracking-2023-09-14.patch
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/activity_tracking.info.yml b/activity_tracking.info.yml
|index bb406b3..ca61b8f 100644
|--- a/activity_tracking.info.yml
|+++ b/activity_tracking.info.yml
--------------------------
patching file activity_tracking.info.yml
Using Plan A...
Hunk #1 FAILED at 5.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file activity_tracking.info.yml.rej
done
```

Patch:

```
diff --git a/activity_tracking.info.yml b/activity_tracking.info.yml
index bb406b3..ca61b8f 100644
--- a/activity_tracking.info.yml
+++ b/activity_tracking.info.yml
@@ -5,5 +5,4 @@ description: 'Allow system to track each activity performed by user.'
 dependencies:
   - drupal:user
   - drupal:system (>=8.1.0)
-core: '8.x'
-core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
+core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10
```

Target:

```
name: Activity Tracking
type: module
description: 'Allow system to track each activity performed by user.'
# core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - drupal:user
  - drupal:system (>=8.1.0)
core: '8.x'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

Comment: I cut-and-pasted your exact files to my machine, and it worked fine.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the response.  I'm running a DDev (Debian 11) container running under WSL Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.  I'm testing running the command from inside the DDev container, but typically I'm calling from the WSL terminal like `ddev composer install`.

Comment: It isn't going to help solve the problem, but if you run the "patch" from your WSL command line, does it work?

Comment: No.  Same error running from WSL terminal.

Comment: You might do a `hexdump -C activity_tracking.info.yml.rej` and look for things characters that seem out of place.  Do you want to put your two files on a sharing service somewhere?

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried hexdump.  I don't see anything out of place, but not sure what I'm looking for.  Here are the files: [https://file.io/YPYWKtJSIwsF](https://file.io/YPYWKtJSIwsF)  
I think I may try to deploy as is, since it seems like it may be a local issue.  As a work-around, I'm thinking I could also use a post-install-cmd hook with sed to get the job done until the library is updated.  What a PITA.  Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: Check if the source file contains a newline character at the end.

Comment: The files in your zip do not match the files you have above.  The patch file above works.  The one in the zip, which matches different lines, does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've identified the issue.

The file that's failing, in your zip, has additional lines after the "core_version_requirement".  That's the issue.  If there are lines following the change, then the patch must include those lines to allow the algorithm to resync, otherwise it's considered a failure.  The patch that you posted above works, because there are no lines after the "core_version_requirement".

That's why it's so important to post the exact files that are failing.

So, if your patch is:

```
diff --git a/activity_tracking.info.yml b/activity_tracking.info.yml
index bb406b3..023b63d 100644
--- a/activity_tracking.info.yml
+++ b/activity_tracking.info.yml
@@ -6,6 +6,6 @@
   - drupal:user
   - drupal:system (>=8.1.0)
 core: '8.x'
-core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
+core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10
 
 # Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2022-03-28
```

then it works.

Comment: That's incredible.  I was testing multiple iterations, so maybe something got fudged in the one I posted.  Regardless.  THANK YOU!!